# Rotating shapes in a canvas with tkinter (python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a Rubik's slide game. Basically, the moves the 4 squares can go are right, left, up, down, clockwise, counterclockwise.

The first button/move i am doing is clockwise. The button makes all the squares shift clockwise once, but how do i make it so that they can keep shifting everytime i press it?

The clockwise movement is the first function, which is then called by the clockwise button.

from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk

```
# --- Functions ---

def clockwise_move():
    canvas.coords(square1, 500, 2, 250, 250)
    canvas.coords(square2, 500, 490, 249, 250)
    canvas.coords(square3, 2, 2, 249, 249)
    canvas.coords(square4, 2, 490, 249, 250)


# --- Setup ---

main = Tk()

main.title("Rubik's Slide")
main.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
main.geometry("700x550")

# --- Objects ---

frame = ttk.Frame(main)
button_frame = ttk.Frame(frame)
canvas = Canvas(frame, width=500, height=700)

# squares
square1 = canvas.create_rectangle(2, 2, 249, 249, fill="red")
square2 = canvas.create_rectangle(500, 2, 250, 250, fill="white")
square3 = canvas.create_rectangle(2, 490, 249, 250, fill="blue")
square4 = canvas.create_rectangle(500, 490, 250, 250, fill="black")

# buttons
right = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Right", command=clockwise_move).grid(column=2, row=1)
left = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Left").grid(column=2, row=2)
up = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Up").grid(column=3, row=1)
down = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Down").grid(column=3, row=2)
clockwise = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Clockwise").grid(column=2, row=3)
counter_clockwise = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Counterclock").grid(column=3, row=3)
start = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Start").grid(column=2, row=4)
reset = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Reset").grid(column=3, row=4)

# frame grid
frame.grid(column=1, row=1)
canvas.grid(column=1, row=1)
button_frame.grid(column=2, row=1)

# misc settings
for child in button_frame.winfo_children():
    child.grid_configure(padx=10, pady=20)

main.mainloop()  # end of GUI
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly what you want to obtain, here's my solution.

I've removed all the buttons except the `clockwise` one in order to simplify the program. I've also simplified the coordinates.

The idea of my program is that for a "clockwise" turn, you have always the same 4 coordinates which are passed to the next square according to the clockwise orientation and according to a counter `n` (i.e. a variable which is always incremented to do some arithmetic in order to index the right coordinates). The operator `*` basically assigns each item of the indexed tuple to the four parameters. The idea of doing something while you press a button can be simulated by listening to the `<Button-1>` and the `<Leave>` events, with a combination of the `after` function, which schedules the call to a function.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


after_id = None

def clockwise_move(e):
    global after_id, c, n
    n += 1

    canvas.coords(square1, *c[n % len(c)])
    canvas.coords(square2, *c[(n + 1) % len(c)])
    canvas.coords(square3, *c[(n + 2) % len(c)])
    canvas.coords(square4, *c[(n + 3) % len(c)])

    after_id = e.widget.after(1000, clockwise_move, e)

def stop(e):
    e.widget.after_cancel(after_id)


main = Tk()

frame = ttk.Frame(main)
button_frame = ttk.Frame(frame)
canvas = Canvas(frame, width=500, height=500)

c = [(0, 0, 250, 250),
     (250, 0, 500, 250),
     (250, 250, 500, 500),
     (0, 250, 250, 500)]

n = len(c)

square1 = canvas.create_rectangle(*c[n % len(c)], fill="red")
square2 = canvas.create_rectangle(*c[(n + 1) % len(c)], fill="yellow")
square3 = canvas.create_rectangle(*c[(n + 2) % len(c)], fill="blue")
square4 = canvas.create_rectangle(*c[(n + 3) % len(c)], fill="green")

clockwise = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Clockwise")
clockwise.grid(column=2, row=3)
clockwise.bind("<Button-1>", clockwise_move)
clockwise.bind("<Leave>", stop)

frame.pack()
canvas.grid(column=1, row=1)
button_frame.grid(column=2, row=1)

for child in button_frame.winfo_children():
    child.grid_configure(padx=10, pady=20)

main.mainloop()
```

Anyway, by looking at the code you'll have a better feeling of what's going on. If not, have a look on the web at the concepts that you haven't understood well yet ;)

There's might be a slight lag when you stop pressing the button because an event has already been scheduled...

Comment: why does it keep rotating? how can i make it just rotate once and not again until i press the button again?

Comment: also, how would i do it for a different direction? I am not seeing were the movement is being done

Comment: @frankehhh I thought you really want to keep it rotating while you press the button, according to your question. You can simply remove this line `after_id = e.widget.after(1000, clockwise_move, e)` and you can also remove this line `clockwise.bind("<Leave>", stop)`. Also, you won't need the function `stop` and the variable `after_id`.

Answer (score 1):

Some more thought is required.  How do you tell the program which row do you want to move, and move it right or left.  The same is true for the columns.  Another tactic is to store the square Id and the color for that square in a dictionary and advance the colors.  This moves rows only, but up and down are similar.

```
from tkinter import *
import ttk
from functools import partial

def move_button(row, direction):
    increment = -1  ## move left
    if direction == "R":
        increment = +1
    this_row=rows_dict[row]
    ## get current leftmost color
    square_instance, color=this_row[0]
    location=colors_list.index(color)
    location += increment  ## next color
    for each_square_list in rows_dict[row]: ## list=square_id and color
        if location >= len(colors_list) or location < 0:
            location = 0
        next_color=colors_list[location]
        print("Setting color to ", next_color)

        ## update the canvas and dictionary with the new color
        canvas.itemconfig(each_square_list[0], fill=next_color)
        each_square_list[1]=next_color
        location += 1  ## for 2nd/right square
    print(rows_dict)

main = Tk()

main.title("Rubik's Slide")
main.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
main.geometry("750x550")

# --- Objects ---

frame = ttk.Frame(main)
button_frame = ttk.Frame(frame)
canvas = Canvas(frame, width=500, height=700)

# store color of each square in a dictionary
# key = row--> list of lists, each square=[ square instance, color]     
rows_dict={}
colors_list=["white", "red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "orange"]
## 2X2 square
square = canvas.create_rectangle(2, 2, 249, 249, fill="red")
rows_dict[0]=[[square, "red"]]
square = canvas.create_rectangle(500, 2, 250, 250, fill="blue")
rows_dict[0].append([square, "blue"])
square = canvas.create_rectangle(2, 490, 249, 250, fill="blue")
rows_dict[1]=[[square, "blue"]]
square = canvas.create_rectangle(500, 490, 250, 250, fill="green")
rows_dict[1].append([square, "green"])
print("rows_dict ", rows_dict)

# buttons
ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Top row right", command=partial(move_button, 0, "R")).grid(column=2, row=0)
ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Top row left", command=partial(move_button, 0, "L")).grid(column=3, row=0)
ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Bottom row right", command=partial(move_button, 1, "R")).grid(column=2, row=1)
ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Bottom row left", command=partial(move_button, 1, "L")).grid(column=3, row=1)
Button(button_frame, text="Exit", command=main.quit, bg="orange").grid(row=5, column=2, columnspan=2)
# frame grid
frame.grid(column=1, row=1)
canvas.grid(column=1, row=1)
button_frame.grid(column=2, row=0, rowspan=2)

# misc settings
for child in button_frame.winfo_children():
    child.grid_configure(padx=10, pady=20)

main.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want to do?

```
import sys
if sys.version[0] < '3':
    from Tkinter import *
else:
    from tkinter import *

left_corners = [(0,0), (200,0), (200,200), (0,200)]
colors = ['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue']

def rotate_clockwise():
    last_color = colors.pop()
    colors.insert(0, last_color)
    update()

def rotate_counterclockwise():
    first_color = colors.pop(0)
    colors.append(first_color)
    update()

def update():
    for square, color in zip(squares, colors):
        canvas.itemconfig(square, fill=color)

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas.grid()

squares = []
for left_corner, color in zip(left_corners, colors):
    x1, y1 = left_corner
    x2, y2 = x1+200, y1+200
    square = canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill=color)
    squares.append(square)

Button(root, text="Rotate 90 degrees clockwise",
       command=rotate_clockwise).grid()
Button(root, text="Rotate 90 degrees counter-clockwise",
       command=rotate_counterclockwise).grid()

root.title("Rotating test")
root.mainloop()
```